# How to use published optional properties correctly for SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, observedobject, swift-optionals

To provide some context, Im writing an order tracking section of our app, which reloads the order status from the server every so-often.  The UI on-screen is developed in SwiftUI.  I require an optional image on screen that changes as the order progresses through the statuses.

When I try the following everything works...

My viewModel is an ObservableObject:
`internal class MyAccountOrderViewModel: ObservableObject {`

This has a published property:
`@Published internal var graphicURL: URL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "tracking_STAGEONE", withExtension: "gif")!`

In SwiftUI use the property as follows:
`GIFViewer(imageURL: $viewModel.graphicURL)`

---

My issue is that the `graphicURL` property has a potentially incorrect placeholder value, and my requirements were that it was optional.  Changing the published property to: `@Published internal var graphicURL: URL?` causes an issue for my GIFViewer which rightly does not accept an optional URL:

`Cannot convert value of type 'Binding<URL?>' to expected argument type 'Binding<URL>'`

Attempting the obvious unwrapping of `graphicURL` produces this error:

`Cannot force unwrap value of non-optional type 'Binding<URL?>'`

---

What is the right way to make this work?  I don't want to have to put a value in the property, and check if the property equals placeholder value (Ie treat that as if it was nil), or assume the property is always non-nil and unsafely force unwrap it somehow.

Comment: What _would_ you like to if the URL is `nil`? You've got to handle it somehow

Comment: Issue is it doesn't work if its optional, if url is nil I would bypass that part of SwiftUI definition.

Comment: So you almost want like an `if let x = ...` kind of thing with the `Binding`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Below is an extension of `Binding` you can use to convert a type like `Binding<Int?>` to `Binding<Int>?`. In your case, it would be `URL` instead of `Int`, but this extension is generic so will work with any `Binding`:

```
extension Binding {
    func optionalBinding<T>() -> Binding<T>? where T? == Value {
        if let wrappedValue = wrappedValue {
            return Binding<T>(
                get: { wrappedValue },
                set: { self.wrappedValue = $0 }
            )
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

With example view:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var model = MyModel()

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 30) {
            Button("Toggle if nil") {
                if model.counter == nil {
                    model.counter = 0
                } else {
                    model.counter = nil
                }
            }

            if let binding = $model.counter.optionalBinding() {
                Stepper(String(binding.wrappedValue), value: binding)
            } else {
                Text("Counter is nil")
            }
        }
    }
}

class MyModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var counter: Int?
}
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Comment: Thanks for a well written and helpful response!

Comment: This one is great, but it gives a "Publishing changes from within view updates is not allowed, this will cause undefined behavior." warning on Xcode 14 :(